# Замена слов в сообщении на другие слова (слова которые надо заменить находятся в массиве)

Tags: node.js

Слова которые находятся в переменной имеют вид

`1
2
3`

Необходимо найти эти слова в другой переменной и заменить на другие слова (можно на одно и то же слово заменить все)

Пока что использую
    `filter.mat.some(fw => {
      if (message.content.includes(fw)) {
      // Код
      }
    }`

(надо сделать переменную заменив слова которые есть в первой переменной на любой текст или на другие слова)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать примерно так -

```js
let sourceText = `a b c d e a b c d e`;
let templateText = `a c e`;

const CONFIGURATION_MAP = {
  'a': 'A',
  'b': 'B',
  'c': 'C',
  'd': 'D',
  'e': 'E',
};

const createMap = (text, map) => text.split(' ').reduce( (result, key) => {
  let value = typeof map === 'object' ? map[key] : map;
  
  return value ? Object.assign(result, {[key]: value}) : result;
}, {} );
const replace = (template, map) => Object.keys(map).reduce( (result, mark) => {
  let regexp = new RegExp( `${mark}`, 'g' );
  let value = map[mark];
  
  return result.replace( regexp, value );
}, template );


let map = createMap(templateText, CONFIGURATION_MAP);
let word = createMap(templateText, '*');

let resultWithMap = replace(sourceText, map);
let resultWithSingleWord = replace(sourceText, word);

console.log(`With map: ${resultWithMap}`);
console.log(`With single word: ${resultWithSingleWord}`);
```

Comment: Все подходит, а можно все заменить на один (Например b на A, d на A и e на A ? (неудобно будет все слова в CONFIGURATION_MAP заносить))

Comment: @sasha0552 внес изменения.